# animation become faster and faster after page update [react.js]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, requestanimationframe

I have this easy animation but I have issue. Everytime I update something on page (for example r of arc) animation become faster and faster after each update or after I saved changes in code.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const CanvasPage = () => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const x = useRef(0);
    const r = 50
    const v = useRef(1);

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        //animation function
        const render = () => { 
            window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

            //bouncing left and right
            x.current = x.current + v.current;
            if(x.current > canvas.width){
                v.current = -1;
            }
            if(x.current <= 0){
                v.current = 1;
            }

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x.current, 75, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.stroke();
        };
        render();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="Canvas">
            <h1>Canvas page</h1>
            <canvas id="canvas" ref={canvasRef} height="500px" width="500px" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default CanvasPage;
```

I have tried all topics regarding with this issue sutch a cancelAnimationFrame() but it did not work.
Can some one help me please?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely because the render function is being triggered on each load. And since `requestAnimationFrame` call is not being cancelled in your code, previous animation function will keep being triggered.

Below fix may solve your issue:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const timerIdHolder = {timerId: null};

        //animation function
        const render = () => { 
            // let's store the last timerId in our ref object
            timerIdHolder.timerId = window.requestAnimationFrame(render);

            //bouncing left and right
            x.current = x.current + v.current;
            if(x.current > canvas.width){
                v.current = -1;
            }
            if(x.current <= 0){
                v.current = 1;
            }

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x.current, 75, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            context.stroke();
        };
        render();

        // let's return a unmount callback
        return () => cancelAnimationFrame(timerIdHolder.timerId);
    }, []);
```

Comment: It works, you are the boss! Thank you very much <3